# align two label-halfs into one with CSS

Tags: html, css

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/unb3n8s1/) here

I have two separate `labels` I want to appear as one.

the `CSS` looks like this

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e0b76d;
}

    .label-main-first {
        position: absolute;
        width: 10%;
        height: 10%;
        top: 50%;
        left: 40%;
        transform: translate(-40%, -50%);
        border: 5px solid green;
        border-right: none;
    }
    /*#a27f40*/
    .label-main-second{
        position: absolute;
        width: 10%;
        height: 10%;
        top: 50%;
        left: 60%;
        transform: translate(-60%, -50%);
        border: 5px solid yellow;
        border-left: none;
    }
```

This creates a gap between the two labels.

Both labels has a width a 10%.

The first label is pushed 40% from the left, while the other label is pushed 60% from the right.

The difference is 20% which is the total width of both labels.

Why am I getting the gap between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `left` value is the percentage of the wrapper (`body` in this case).

The percentage in `translate` is the percentage of its own `width`.

The second label starts at the middle, so it does not require X value for translate. `transform: translate(0%, -50%);`

The first label need to translate 100% of its width to the left. `transform: translate(-100%, -50%);`

The below code helps to align all in the center in properly.

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #e0b76d;
}

.label-main-first {
position: absolute;
width: 10%;
height: 10%;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
border: 5px solid green;
border-right: none;
}
/*#a27f40*/
.label-main-second{
position: absolute;
width: 10%;
height: 10%;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(0%, -50%);
border: 5px solid yellow;
border-left: none;
}
```

```html
  <label for="input-main" class="label-main-first"></label>
    <label for="input-main" class="label-main-second"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure over the goals that you have by using these style, but will suggest more one solution a bit simpler, https://jsfiddle.net/unb3n8s1/1/
hope it will work for your purposes also.

```
  <div class="wrapper"><label for="input-main" class="label-main-first"></label>
      <label for="input-main" class="label-main-second"></label></div>
```

you can change width, height and also set position absolute for wrapper, instead of each label.

Here is Variant with percents: https://jsfiddle.net/unb3n8s1/2/

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e0b76d;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 20%;
    height: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 40%;
}
label {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
.label-main-first {
    border: 5px solid green;
    border-right: none;
}
/*#a27f40*/
.label-main-second{
    border: 5px solid yellow;
    border-left: none;
}
```

Comment: The labels have percentage width, not fixed width. And also need horizontal and vertical center alignment.

Comment: You are right, updated with percentage variant also.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's simply because the first label has left value of 40% and width of 10%
so the second label should have left value of 50% instead of 60%